# Spring URLs: There's a difference between "/test" and "/test/" in the controller mapping

Tags: java, html, url, spring-mvc

Simple example spring controller (if you're not familiar with spring, just look at the output html):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("")
    @ResponseBody
    public String pathTest(){
        return "<html><head></head><body><a href='subpath'>subpath</a></body></html>";
    }
}
```

If I go to **http://mydomain/test**, the link from the above html goes to: **http://mydomain/subpath**

If I go to **http://mydomain/test/**, the link from the above html goes to: **http://mydomain/test/subpath**

I guess this is simple, but I don't know how to ensure that the trailing '/' doesn't affect the application function. My primary concern is when users manually change the URL, they may or may not leave the trailing '/'.

What can I do to ensure my application works the same whether or not the final '/' exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not return `<a href='subpath'>subpath</a>` return

`<a href='/test/subpath'>subpath</a>` instead.